# Debug Qt signals, slots and connections

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

Is there a way to see which signals are fired, and if there is a slot connected to them?  Ideally, we'd like to see *all* signals, not just those of a particular class or method; e.g. [QSignalSpy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html) only allows us to track specific signals of specific instances.

In our application, we've seen performance problems because of a signal being emitted twice from different components.  In the end, it turned out that there was a second instance of a class that should have only been there once.  Knowing which signals are emitted exactly helps in debugging this.

Signals are called via `QMetaObject::invoke*`, I was hoping to find something there to hook into, but I found nothing obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to intercept ALL signals emitted by a given event in QT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072013/how-to-intercept-all-signals-emitted-by-a-given-event-in-qt)

Comment: If you want to have just one instance of the class, why didn't you use the singleton pattern to control number of objects?

Answer (score 5):

(disclaimer, I work for KDAB) : KDAB's [GammaRay tool](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/wiki/Getting-GammaRay) can show you objects and connections at runtime, without requiring any source changes. It inspects the meta-object tables and does some code-injection hooks to make this work.

Comment: I built GammaRay from the git repo and could not find where connections are shown (built with Qt 5.7); the Signals panel just showed emission tics. The best I could do as an alternative was to remove the check for QT_DEBUG in qobject.cpp and call dumpObjectInfo() to see all signal/slot connections of the object, otherwise it printed nothing for my -debug-and-release configured Qt build.

Answer (score 1):

[`QSignalSpy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html) could help you.

From docs,

> The QSignalSpy class enables introspection of signal emission.QSignalSpy can connect to any signal of any object and records its emission.

The docs has examples too..

Comment: I am aware of signal spy, sorry for not mentioning that.  The downside of it, is that it does not allow me to see *all* emitted signals, just specific signal signatures of a single class or instance.

Comment: @Ivo, I am not sure whether there is anything which lists all the signals emitted but yes `QSignalMapper` is to track the signals from the specified instance..

Comment: Qt maintains a list of signals internally, which is a struct containing at least the string containing the signal name and signature.  That much I gathered from looking at the code.  However, unfortunately, this is buried very deep in Qt.