# Qt slots called from QtScript in a threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I've made my application scriptable by creating a derived QThread class, where I add multiples QObject class in order to access their functions via the command line.

```
void commandLine::addObject(QObject *obj, QString name)
{
  QScriptValue sv = m_scriptEngine.newQObject(obj);
  m_scriptEngine.globalObject().setProperty(name, sv);

  qObjectMap.insert(std::pair<QString, QObject *>(name, obj));
}
```

After the run() call, the class enter in an infinite loop, using m_scriptEngine to evaluate every command line entered.

In my (simplified) main I do :

```
simuCLI cli;
simuCore core;
cli.addObject(&core, "core");
simuUI ui;
connect(&ui, SIGNAL(start()), &core, SLOT(start()));
```

**But when I call start() from my GUI and from my script, results are differents**

My application architecture is like the following :

> Core -> StateMachine -> Machine -> Communication

Start from UI works great.

Start from command line execute the code, but don't launch the QStateMachine and it emit signals, but never receive them.

`Communication` sends commands to `Machine` by emiting signals received in `Machine`. It works if I've call core::start() from my UI
If I call core::start() using my command lines signal is emited but never received.

```
void WL::WL()
{
  std::cout << "wl cst" << std::endl;
  mLectMotStateMachine.setInitialState(sNoCard);
  mLectMotStateMachine.start();
}
void WL::enterNoCard()
{
  std::cout << "no card" << std::endl;
}
```

**Ouput :**

start() from UI :

```
wl cst
no card
```

start() from command line :

```
wl cst
```

As you can see, the state machine never enter in it first state, like it never launch.

So my questions are :

**1 - In wich thread is executing start() if I call it from command line ?**

**2 - How can I debug signals ? ([best answer I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072013/how-to-intercept-all-signals-emitted-by-a-given-event-in-qt))**

**3 - Is there a way to see every Signals connection at a time 't' on execution**

**4 - How can I know in which thread I am on execution ?**

**5 - Have you any ideas of why my code isn't working only when I use the command line ?**

Comment: Check your connects, especially the connection start() should be activated with. For any further help post code please.

Comment: I've fully edited my post to be more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it is an error to directly call thread-unsafe methods in the objects that reside in other threads. I presume that the `simuCore` object is a `QThread` and creates a bunch of other objects in its thread. Those objects cannot be accessed from other threads *directly* unless you make their methods thread safe (you demonstrably don't).

The answers are:

1. You can check it. Within the `start()` method, add:

   ```
   qDebug() << QThread::currentThread();
   ```

   You'll see that it's the same thread as `qApp->thread()`, also known as the main thread or the gui thread.
2. I don't know what you mean by debugging signals. The signal-slot mechanism obviously works, so what is there to debug?
3. Why would you need that? You're the one who is making (and breaking) the connections, so you can certainly add debug output at the point where you make and break those connections. No magic to it.
4. `QThread::currentThread()`.
5. Because you're:

   - Calling thread-unsafe methods from threads other than the thread where the object resides.
   - Deriving from `QThread` when you shouldn't.

   You should, instead, simply move the script engine object to a plain dedicated `QThread` (no subclassing), and use thread-safe method invocation to evaluate the command lines. Signal-slot connections are thread-safe, as well as `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

For example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <QThread>

class ScriptEngine : public QScriptEngine {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_SIGNAL void evaluateSignal(const QString &);
public:
   Q_SLOT void evaluate(const QString & str) { QScriptEngine::evaluate(str); }
   /// A thread-safe evaluate()
   Q_SLOT void safeEvaluate(const QString & str) { emit evaluateSignal(str); }
   explicit ScriptEngine(QObject * parent = 0) : QScriptEngine(parent) {
      connect(this, &ScriptEngine::evaluateSignal, this, &ScriptEngine::evaluate);
   }
};

class Thread : public QThread {
   // A thread that's safe to destruct, like it ought to be
   using QThread::run; // final
public:
   ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  ScriptEngine engine;
  Thread worker;
  engine.globalObject().setProperty("qApp", engine.newQObject(qApp));
  engine.moveToThread(&worker);
  worker.start();

  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&engine, "evaluate", Q_ARG(QString, "print('Hi!')"));
  engine.safeEvaluate("print('And hello!')");
  engine.safeEvaluate("qApp.quit()");
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Wow thanks. This is the real implementation of a QThread. I've found [this](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) who can be helpful.

Comment: And a great exemple from Qt Dev Andre on [the QThread class ref](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#notes).

Comment: Note: The `qApp.quit()` call is a race with `app.exec()`, there's  a chance that it will be executed on the worker thread before `app.exec()` enters and then it will be a no-op. TODO later :)