# Sender in signal-to-signal connection

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qobject

There is a function `QObject::sender()`, than, when invoked in a slot, provides the `QObject*` pointer to the sending object.

It's behaviour is far less useful if you have the following structure.

```
class A : public QObject { Q_OBJECT 
    ...
    signals: 
        void foo(); 
};

class B : public QObject { Q_OBJECT 
    ...
    signals: 
        void foo(); 
};

class C : public QObject { Q_OBJECT
    ... 
    public slots: 
        void bar() { qDebug() << sender(); }  
};

A a; 
B b;
C c;


connect(&A, SIGNAL(foo()), &B, SIGNAL(foo()));
connect(&B, SIGNAL(foo()), &C, SLOT(bar()));

A::whatever() { emit foo(); }
```

`C::bar()` indicates `B` as the emitter. How can I get the original emitting object, without dealing with all the relays?

Unfortunately `QObject::sender()` is `protected` so this naive approach in `C::bar()` wouldn't compile (not sure if it ever could work, but that's my only idea to traverse the `sender()` backwards):

```
QObject *ptr = this;
while ((ptr = ptr->sender()) != NULL)
    qDebug() << ptr->objectName();
```

---

To answer some of the questions raised in comments:

- `A` - custom widget (lots of dynamically created ones) (holding some data, pointers, whatnot)
- `B` - custom top-level UI element (member of the `QStackedWidget`, handles some UI responsibilities)
- `C` - (in practice, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`) - work that needs to be performed (using common state, such as DSP queue) on data stored in As.

Ultimately, `A` needs to know very little about `C`s (or even if anything cares about it's signals). `B` is where the UI aggregation takes place (also the top-level UI calls `C`s to set DSP parameters etc). `C`s need to know if `sender()` is `qobject_cast`'able to `IA` interface.

It can be reworked to something along the lines of:

```
class A : public QObject { Q_OBJECT 
    ...
    signals: 
        void foo(QObject*); 
};

class B : public QObject { Q_OBJECT 
    ...
    signals: 
        void foo(QObject*); 
};

class C : public QObject { Q_OBJECT
    ... 
    public slots: 
        void bar(QObject* mySender) { qDebug() << mySender; }  
};

A a; 
B b;
C c;


connect(&A, SIGNAL(foo(QObject*)), &B, SIGNAL(foo(QObject*)));
connect(&B, SIGNAL(foo(QObject*)), &C, SLOT(bar(QObject*)));

A::whatever() { emit foo(this); }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get a sort of "stacktrace" for the emitted signals. I believe signal emitting is a sort of function call. So you want to know which objects' functions were called before it reached your object C? Hm, but why? Anyways, this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072013/how-to-intercept-all-signals-emitted-by-a-given-event-in-qt

Comment: It's almost a function call. It is however setting the ::sender() pointers at (perhaps) each level of signal indirection - in the simple SIGNAL-SLOT connection, the SLOT can detect which object caused the signal that invoked the SLOT. This can be easily used to do custom multiple callers - slot invocations. I could refactor the SIGNAL() to include QObject* as a parameter, and it will be relayed correctly, but.. it's a cludge.

Comment: Well, but why do you need this? Perhaps there is another way to solve your problem?

Comment: The simplest method here is to connect A's signal to C's slot. Why do you need to go via B? It sounds like you should redesign the hierarchy.

Comment: @Merlin069 - answered your concerns in my edit.

Comment: @vahancho - ditto :)

Comment: @qdot, You said: "C need to know if sender() is qobject_cast'able to IA interface.". I would say "No" on this. This should be defined in the place where you establish your connections. Function has not to know who calls it.

Comment: That's even more confusing. So, you have A (data model) B (UI) C (worker). I would expect B to connect to C and C to connect to A, but not B to A in this instance. So, when a user interacts with the UI, it sets a worker going, which does something, changes the values in the data model and updates the UI. Alternatively, if you're using a Qt data model, the UI gets automatically updated, based upon Qt's Model View Framework: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

Comment: @Merlin069 The trick is - not all connections between A and C fire at all times - depending on the UI, we might choose to either disconnect and reconnect all A's to C1, or all A's to C2.. or just reconnect the B-C relay (while using the exact same semantics so it's possible to do A-C connections without UI if the functionality is fixed)

Comment: @vahancho Perhaps you're right. The Observer-Observable pattern allows the Observer (C) to identify the Observable (A), but, in my explicit passing of `this` as `QObject* mySender` we can make it explicit that the `bar()` works on the parameter instead of implicit data passing.

Comment: @qdot hello from the past. :) sorry, but how did you solve it at the end? i have the same problem now. my A should know, is he a root reason of changes in C, because C informing A about changes in it. and i have happy loop. :)